# Get request host name from secure source?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm doing security checks on a website, and we have some code that does stuff like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getScheme()%>://<%=request.getServerName() %>:<%=request.getServerPort()%><%= request.getContextPath() %>/css/<fmt:bundle basename="version"><fmt:message key="build.date"/><fmt:message key="js.path.separator"/></fmt:bundle>${relativePath}" media="all" type="text/css" />
```

The underlying reasoning is to construct a CSS path with the build version in it, to force the browser to load the latest CSS file and avoid caching issues.

Unfortunately, the first part of the construction uses `request.getServerName()` to construct the URL.   It turns out that this refers back to the HOST header from the incoming request.  This is a security vulnerability because the header can be spoofed, causing the resulting link to refer to another site and not to the local site.

Is there a more secure way of doing this?  I've thought of putting a value in the application context but wondered if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: you should have config file with desired name, do not try to calculate/obtain the name in runtime, host could be behind load balancer, http headers can be wrong and so on

Comment: @Ilya_Bursov, very good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need the scheme, the serverName, or the serverPort to construct your URL since those all default to being relative to the current request.

If you have a page at `https://example.com:8081/project/pages/things.html` then a link within that like your example `/project/css/<version><build-date>.css` resolves to `https://example.com:8081/project/css/<version><build-date>.css` anyway, so you can leave those parts off

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= request.getContextPath()
     %>/css/<fmt:bundle basename="version">
            <fmt:message key="build.date"/>
            <fmt:message key="js.path.separator"/>
            </fmt:bundle>${relativePath}" media="all" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: its great solution for web pages, but sometimes you need full absolute url (for example in e-mails, rss, etc)

Comment: Agreed @IlyaBursov, but the question is tagged java+jsp ... that said, I do keep a config for my java+jsp web application myself, locked down outside of the web & tomcat space.

Comment: Thanks, these are both good suggestions; I'll see what the management wants to do.   Much appreciated!